# How do I output 4 random records from the database and store them in 4 different variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to output 4 random records from the database and store them in 4 different variables.
I would like to continue working with the variables.
How do I get this done?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carditems WHERE status = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4 ");
$stmt->execute([1]);

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    var_dump($row['idItem']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carditems WHERE status = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4 ");
    $stmt->execute([1]);
    $array = [];
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     $array[] = $row['idItem'];
    }
  var_dump($array);
```

It's not 4 variables, but 4 array elements to be used further in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using PDO method `fetchAll()` and PHP method `list`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carditems WHERE status = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4 ");
$stmt->execute([1]);


list($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4) = $stmt->fetchAll();

var_dump($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4);
```

`fetchAll` get all records into array,
`list` decomposits array to separate variables. In case when array have less values then list variables count the variables will be `NULL`

[PHP PDO test online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/62fc63e3b77dffc151486eae77e3ab82/php/php8/20ed5f33c15b7f8409f714b805d808e3/)